# вопрос про массивов

Tags: java, массивы

В одном тесте я встретил пункты

- array.length
- array.length()

конечно я знаю, что правильный из них это array.length, но решил за интерес поэкспериментировать в Intellij Idea.

Взял и намеренно поставил скобки после length и самое интересное, описание ошибки компилятора меня удивило...

Описание ошибки такое "method call expected"

Вроде по правилам, вызов метода предполагает наличие скобок, только
поля не имеют скобок.

Решил посмотреть, что пишет Intellij когда я просто ставлю точку после array. 
в списке приводит пункт "length" а значок не "m" а "f"...  в смысле функция?

И тут у меня появился вопрос:

Почему length без скобок считается методом со стороны компилятора если оно не имеет скобок?

Comment: потому что в массивах .length это не метод, а поле класса, переменная.

Comment: Скобки поставили вы - поэтому считается, что вы хотите метод и Intellij вам намекает что нет такого метода. *"f"... в смысле функция?* Нет, в смысле "**f**ield" (поле).

Comment: @pavlofff это таки я понял до того как прочел вот это "Описание ошибки такое "method call expected"" , если бы в ошибке не была написана, что ожидается метод, то данный вопрос не возник бы. Так как я знаю, что переменные обьявляются без скобок. Мне интересно, почему компилятор называет методом, то что является полем.

Comment: @woesss то, что Intellij намекает, что нет того, чего я хочу от него получить, это я знаю, ну специально ведь сделал эксперимент и прекрасно знаю, что того чего я хочу, тот не может предоставить, но удивило меня именно описание ошибки Intellij, что получается, что то что я его дал, не является методом, а поле, которое должно было быть вызвана, является методом... у меня в мыслях было одно "компилятор, ты часом не перепутал местами понятия поле и метод?"

Comment: Компилятор что видит, то и читает. Поле здесь вообще не при чём - java не запрещает назвать поле и метод одинаковым именем. Поэтому компилятор видит ваши скобки и ищет в классе метод, которого нет. А поле при этом его не интересует никак - есть оно с таким же именем или нет.

Answer (score 2):

Обращясь к переменным (полям) скобки не ставятся, они необходимы только при вызове функций (методов), куда должны передаваться параметры (или не должны, в зависимости от самой функции).

В объектно-ориентированных языках можно различать подобные вещи ещё по именам. Как правило, если вам требуется какое-либо свойство объекта (в данном случае, длина массива), и если это свойство объявлено у него как `private`, то разработчики составляют ему соответствующие методы доступа геттеры и сеттеры. Для длины это было бы `getLength()`. Но так как в классе объекта массива поле `length` объявлено как `public` обращение к нему не нуждается в геттерах и сеттерах.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, но дело в том, что мой вопрос возник не на основе того, что меня удивило, что перед переменной не ставят скобки, а то что компилятор считает поле - методом. так как при намеренном эксперименте "поставил скобки" компилятор говорит, что ожидается метод, а не поле. Вот что увело меня в заблуждение.

Comment: но ваш ответ меня заинтересовал. Откуда вы получили доступ к поле length? я какие горячие клавиши не пробовал, не дает мне получить доступ к классу обьекта массива, да и в каком то смысле мне ясно почему не удается, но все же, как вы получили этот доступ?

Comment: Доступ - имеется в виду чтение/запись значения поля в коде.

Comment: Как и указал вам [woesss](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/11515/woesss) в комментариях, компилятор указал, что при такой записи он собирается вызвать метод, но такого метода не существует.

Comment: И под доступом понимается всё, что объявлено 'public'. Такие открытые интерфейсы (методы доступа) позволяют изменять состояние объекта класса (то есть поля, объявленные как 'private').